# Proof of "For each integer m, the set S = {i ∈ Z : i ≥ m} is well-ordered."

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation, well-orders

This is question 6.17 from Mathematical Proofs by Chartrand/Polimeni/Zhang.

**Prove**: For each integer $m$, the set $S = \{i ∈ Z : i ≥ m\}$ is well-ordered.

The given proof in the back of the book states:

**Proof**: We need only show that every nonempty subset of $S$ has a least element. So let $T$ be a nonempty subset of $S$. If $T$ is a subset of $N$, then, by the Well-Ordering Principle, $T$ has a least element. Hence we may assume that $T$ is not a subset of $N$. Thus $T − N$ is a finite nonempty set and so contains a least element $t$. Since $t ≤ 0$, it follows that $t ≤ x, \forall x ∈ T$ ; so $t$ is a least element of $T$.

Here's where I get lost: I get that $T - N$ is a finite, nonempty set. I do not get why this implies it must contain a least element $t$. Is it because of the fact it is finite? Are we using the knowledge that, while $Z$ does not contain a least element, any finite subset of $Z$ *does* contain a least element?

Also: I get why this $t \in T - N \leq 0$, but I don't get why we then know $t \leq x, \forall x \in T$. Is it because we've have concluded that this element $t$ is the least element of $T - N$? I feel like I'm on the verge of getting it, but it isn't quite all adding up.

Comment: Yes, indeed a finite set of integers contains a least element. That's clear, isn't it?

Comment: This is not a duplicate "per se", but the actual question is the same. One more reason why the question should be *the question*, rather than the context. (I'm not complaining about the set up, well done on explaining the issue.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, thank you; I should have made the question the actual question, not the context. I will keep that in mind for future questions. Thanks again!